# AWSのEBSスナップショット一覧を取得してメールする方法

Tags: aws, amazon-ec2, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

現在AWSのEC2を使用しているシステムで日々EBSスナップショットを取得していますが、顧客から一ヶ月毎にスナップショットを一覧にしてメール送付して欲しいとの要求がありました。（スナップショットID,ボリュームID,取得日時）
EBSスナップショットはライフサイクルマネージャーで取得しS3に保存されていますが、このS3バケットはユーザーから隠匿されているみたいでスナップショット一覧の取得方法に悩んでいます。
ご対応方法をご教示いただけないでしょうか。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Amazon EBS スナップショットに関する情報の表示](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ja_jp/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ebs-describing-snapshots.html)にはAWSコンソールでの一覧表示やAWS CLI他APIでの取得方法も説明されています。いずれの方法であっても最終的には[DescribeSnapshots](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/APIReference/API_DescribeSnapshots.html)が呼ばれています。

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございました。Lambdaを使用してAPIで取得する方法で検討してみます。